# jquery mobile add listview to " navbar in footer "

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, header, footer

I want to add areas instead of links to navbar in footer, then add a list view to one of the areas.
Navbar accept only anchors not divs and list view style is not correct into the following example:

http://jsfiddle.net/syr2v/

Comment: would this work? http://jsfiddle.net/phillpafford/syr2v/1/

Comment: @PhillPafford No, 1)every line ListView must contain one item per line as usual ListView, 2) scroll needed for the rest of ListView items. Many Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution but it should get you started:

- http://jsfiddle.net/phillpafford/syr2v/2/

Comment: Please why previous code not working if saved in html file
[http://jsfiddle.net/syr2v/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/syr2v/3/)